# How to get selected value in jQuery autocompleter

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery auto completer and getting the values from a jsp.When i specify some source i can use the following code to get the selected value.

```
   $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

When i use like this

```
 $("#query").autocomplete("list.jsp");
```

How i can use the select event.Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

It is not the way you are thinking.source must mentioned to get the input values list from jsp.After selection of item there is no matter of source.You have to handle the select event to get the correct value.you want to know which item has been selected

```
 $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function (event, ui) {
             var val= ui.item.value;
             //Do some thing  here if user selects right value 
        }
    });
```

See to map source :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#jquery_from_ob").autocomplete({
        source: "getblocks.jsp",
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
</script>
```

Reference:http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: can i specify jsp in place of source

Comment: So,you want to get the values from jsp  ?? or you want to know which value has been selected ??

Comment: the value  what i selected in the second case means when i use jsp

Comment: what ever you use,the value comes in to select event.Use there.

Comment: can u modify this $("#query").autocomplete("list.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $( "#query" ).autocomplete({
           source: "list.jsp",
           minLength: 2
 });
```